Проблема с медиазапросами в SCSS
Я столкнулась с проблемой при использовании медиазапросов в своем проекте на SCSS. Когда я проверяю работу медиазапросов, отображаются только красный и синий цвет на максимальных ширинах 1400px и 992px, а на меньших ширинах ничего не происходит.
Я также пробовала добавлять медиазапросы напрямую в файл main.scss, но это не сработало.
ссылка на гитхаб https://github.com/unenl1ghtened/coca
Если у кого-то есть идеи о том, как это исправить, буду очень благодарна за помощь!

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

У вас не прописан Viewport, поэтому он не знает что такое размеры - 

В head нужно вставить

Спасибо большое!! Помогло!
